# printing values returned from scala function

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

```
object TestClass {
  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello World");
    val c = List (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    println(findMax(c))
  }
  def findMax (tempratures: List[Int]) {
    tempratures.foldLeft(Integer.MIN_VALUE) {Math.max}
  }
}
```

Output shown is

```
Hello World 
()
```

Why is the output not

```
Hello World
10
```

I'm doing this in IntelliJ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the most common scala typos.

You're missing the `=` at the end of your method:

```
def findMax (tempratures: List[Int]) {
```

Should read:

```
def findMax (tempratures: List[Int]) = {
```

Leaving the `=` off means that your method returns `Unit` (nothing).

Comment: now i feel like a dummie :). so `=` signifies that this method returns something?

Comment: @Omnipresent: every method returns something, but without `=` the return type is always `Unit`, i.e. `()`. Keep in mind, that Scala is designed to be functional language, and in functional programming almost each construction returns value, even such things as `if`: `val x = if b { ifVal } { elseVal }`.

Answer (score 7):

Because you define `findMax` without return type, so the return type is `Unit` or `()`.

```
def findMax (tempratures: List[Int]) { ... }
```

aka

```
def findMax (tempratures: List[Int]) : Unit = { ... }
```

You want instead

```
def findMax (tempratures: List[Int]) : Int = { ... }
```

or with omitted type

```
def findMax (tempratures: List[Int]) = { ... }
```